# Capture scroll event on div

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events, marionette

I'm trying to capture the scroll event within a Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView, but without success.

As an exercise, I'm rewriting http://www.atinux.fr/backbone-books/ using Backbone.Marionette. As you can see, when you scroll down, more books are fetched and displayed (i.e.  infinite scroll). However, I'm unable to capture the scroll event on my view.

Here's my (simplified) code:

```
  LibraryView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    // properties, initializer, etc.

    events: {
      'scroll': 'loadMoreBooks',
      'click': 'loadMoreBooks'
    },

    // some functions

    loadMoreBooks: function(){
      console.log("loadMoreBooks");
    }
  });
```

The full source code can be seen here: https://github.com/davidsulc/backbone.marionette-atinux-books/blob/scroll/assets/javascript/app.js#L86-89

What I don't understand is that the "click" event is being triggered properly, but the "scroll" event isn't. What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit: so the error was pretty simple in the end... I was passing "el: #content" to the view's contructor, but the scroll was defined in CSS on ".library". So once I changed my DOM from

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="library">
  </div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div id="content" class="library"></div>
```

everything worked properly...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: { "scroll": "scroll" },
  scroll: function(){ console.log( "scrolling..." ); }
});
```

[Check the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/fGtZk/)

As @JoshLeitzel said I think the issue is in the DOM element it self.

Try to by-pass Backbone doing:

```
$("#content").bind( "scroll", function(){ console.log( "scrolling from jquery directly" ); } );
```

Also try to replace:

```
el: $('#content')
```

by

```
el: '#content'
```

I don't think this is the issue but is the new style of `el` definition :)

Comment: Your answer helped me solve the issue, thanks. (See my edit.)

Answer (score 16):

Backbone attaches to the top *el* element to look for *all* events.  Some DOM events are not bubbled to parent elements and this includes *scroll*.  The click event worked because it does bubble.

Ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20090908/#event-type-scroll

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what your `el` is, but I suspect it's something that does not receive the `scroll` event. Since Backbone delegates event handling to jQuery, have a look at what jQuery says about the [`scroll` event](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/):

> The `scroll` event is sent to an element when the user scrolls to a
>   different place in the element. It applies to `window` objects, but also
>   to scrollable frames and elements with the `overflow` CSS property set
>   to scroll (or `auto` when the element's explicit height or width is less
>   than the height or width of its contents).

Unless your `el` satisfies those conditions, it will not receive the `scroll` event. You will have to put the event handler on `window` or some other element that does receive it.

Comment: The `el` is a div with a fixed height and `overflow-y` set to `scroll`. In other words, it should receive the scroll event. Any other idea what might be wrong?

Comment: SO in the end, the container I was binding to wasn't the same as the one I was defining a scroll on (see my edit). But have an upvote for your help ;-)