# 'scroll' event not firing in CompositeView

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I saw the [Capture scroll event on div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258270/capture-scroll-event-on-div) ticket, but the solution didn't necessarily work for me.

I have a JSFiddle that renders a Collection via a CompositeView, but can not get the scroll event to fire (building an infinite scroll): http://jsfiddle.net/franklovecchio/FkNwG/300/.

How can I get `scroll` to fire correctly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First scroll event only works for element that have overflow: scroll/auto. In your case it is the #region-content and not the #container.

But fixing the selector for events  will not work, because Backbone uses jquery .delegate() to attach it's events. But delegate fails to trigger for scroll events.

I am afraid you will have to attach the event manually, after rendering the dom with

```
$("#region-content").scroll () ->
  console.log "ok"
```

You can use live() to attach the events.

Alternatively, you can make #content scrollable and scroll that. This will work, as Backbone will not be use delegate, but it will bind the event directly to the #content node.

Comment: or without the lazy load like so http://jsfiddle.net/bGgVw/

Your views always create div containers and by default the events are attached to that. So binding the scroll event to the generated div and changing the overflow to 

`#container > div {
   height: 100px;
   overflow: scroll;
}`