# Capture scroll event in Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I have a Backbone.Marionette item view. It renders a list of items. I want to listen for the scoll event everytime somebody scrolls the list. I assumed this would work:

```
events: {
    'scroll ul': 'filterInteraction'
},

filterInteraction: function(){
    console.log('in filterInteraction ');
}
```

But it does not capture the scroll event. However, when I do:

```
onRender: function() {
     this.$el.find('ul').on( 'scroll', function(){
         console.log('scroll event captured'):  
     });
}
```

This will capture the scroll event. What is the difference? Both seem to be doing the same thing...

Comment: Any help from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258270/capture-scroll-event-on-div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have 4 event handler :

- scroll

  - for root div : el
  - for ul
- click

  - for root div : el
  - for ul

the 'click' event bubble so in event delagation the div #root receive it and can handle it, but the scroll event don't bubble so we can't handle it from #root div

In the next example we have the same code for each event.

If we click on 'ul' we have a log `click for ul` and a log `click for #root` 
because click event 'bubble' / climb up the DOM tree until #root.
If we scroll on #root we have a log `scroll for root` because we capture the event directly from it.
But we can't use event delegation to handle scroll from ul because scroll event don't 'bubble' / climb up the DOM tree.

[scroll on w3 site](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20090908/#event-type-scroll)

```js
var dbg = $('#dbg')
var log = function(val){
  dbg.append('<div>' + val + '</div>')
  .scrollTop(99999);
};
$('button').click(function(){dbg.empty() });



var i=0;
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  
  events : {
    
    'click' : 'elClick' ,
    'scroll' :'elScroll' ,
    
    'click ul' : 'ulClick' ,
    'scroll ul' :'ulScroll' ,

  } ,
  elScroll : function(){ log('scroll for #root : '  + (i++)); } ,
  ulScroll : function(){ log('scroll for ul : '     + (i++)); } ,
  elClick  : function(){ log('clicked on #root :  ' + (i++)); } ,
  ulClick  : function(){ log('clicked on ul  : '    + (i++)); } ,
}); 

myView = new MyView({el : $('#root') });
```

```css
#dbg{
  position: aboslute;
  border : solid 1px #EEE;
  top : 0;
  left : 0;
  right :0;
  height : 150px;
  min-height : 150px;
  overflow : auto;
  bottom : auto;
}
#dbg:hover{
    bottom : 0;
    height : auto;
}

#root{
    position: aboslute;
  border : solid 1px #EEE;
  top : 30px;
  left : 0;
  right :0;
  height : 150px;
  overflow : auto
  }
ul,li {
  border:solid 1px #CCC;
  list-style : none;
  padding : 0px;
  margin : 1px;
  cursor : pointer;
  }
ul{
  height : 200px;
  overflow : auto; 
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone-min.js"></script>

<div id='dbg'>debug : </div>
<div id='root'>
  <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    
  </ul>
  
</div><button>clear debug</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

With onRender you are setting the event on each render that's the only difference I see. So in my opinion the first solution would have better performance.

And as anonymousday said, the first option is implementing event delegation, which means *Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.*
http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: No this is not the only difference ! Event Delegation is what happen in the first case but not in the second

Comment: (scroll on w3 site)[www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20090908/#event-type-scroll]    The problem with the scroll event it is it don't `Bubbles`, the parent node never receive the 'event bubbling'

Comment: so you mean it's pointless to implement event delegation for scrolling ?

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible without bubbling, i'll try to provide a snippet !